# iOS - NavigationBar showing on child controller, hidden on parent controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have implemented a custom version of a search form that behaves a lot like a UISearchBar with a scope bar (but is actually pieced together programatically for UI reasons). The screen loads with a TextField, you tap in the TextField and the navigation bar animates up off the screen, the text field moves up and a segmented control appears for filtering results.

Anyway, that all works, but when I tap on one of the search results my code pushes a new ViewController. The problem is that new controller gets pushed without a navigation bar (because I used `[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES]` when switching to the search state).

I can show the navigation bar as the new ViewController gets pushed, or even animate it in as the transition to the new ViewController appears - but all those solutions look clunky. I want it to work as if you were using a UISearchBar (actually more like the email app) in that the restored navigation bar appears to just slide in from the right as if it's part of the child view controller.

I'm hoping there'll be a simple fix... thanks

Comment: One way to get the behavior your want is to simply nest the new `UIViewController` in a completely separate `UINavigationController`

Comment: That's a decent idea and worth pursuing if I can't think of anything else. The problems are that I don't get the 'back' button in the navigation bar of the new ViewController to get back to the search (at least not without some extra fiddling, which I'm kind of hoping to avoid).

Comment: Perhaps, although the "extra fiddling" can be quite minimal (a one liner, essentially).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone that comes to this, the solution is to make your controller the delegate of the `UINavigationController`, then show or hide the nav bar in your delegate methods.

Your controller needs to implement the protocol:

```
@interface MYSearchController() <UINavigationControllerDelegate>
```

Then in `-(void)viewDidLoad` assign your controller as the delegate:

```
[self navigationController].delegate = self;
```

Finally, implement a method like this:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if(viewController == self)
    {
        if(_searchState && ![self navigationController].navigationBarHidden)
        {
            [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if([self navigationController].navigationBarHidden)
        {
            [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm working on this problem with Xcode 5.1/iOS7 and the setNavigationBarHidden is ignored in my case. Seems something may have changed, delegate is fired but no change in the view, still hidden as a result of doing a filter on a table view using a search display controller. It's pointing me in the right direction though so +1